# fatal error: 'common.h' file not found under mac osx 10.10.5

Tags: c++, c, macos

I follow the book **Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces**, the code in [introduction chapter](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/intro.pdf),

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include "common.h"

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (argc != 2)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: cpu <string>\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  char *str = argv[1];
  while(1)
  {
    Spin(1);
    printf("%s\n", str);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

When I try `gcc -o cpu cpu.c -Wall`,

The error came out: **fatal error: 'common.h' file not found**,

I have tried download common.h from [this link](http://ftp.stu.edu.tw/BSD/OpenBSD/src/lib/csu/common.h), and put this file with cpu.c, but it doesn't work, error message:

```
cpu.c:8:1: error: conflicting types for 'main'
main(int argc, char *argv[])
^
./common.h:86:13: note: previous declaration is here
extern int              main(int, char **, char **);
                        ^
cpu.c:18:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'Spin' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    Spin(1);
    ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
```

How to fix the error? Thanks.

Comment: @shami thanks, I see.

Comment: i added as answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `"common.h"` header for this problem is linked as a tgz bundle in the table of contents for the course next to chapter 1: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/

Drop it next to your source file and try compiling again.

Comment: Why not just add the link `http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/Code/code.intro.tgz`

Comment: @color-blind my experience with the course suggested the directory structure below what I linked was being reworked quite a bit. I wanted the parent to be able to find the file, even if the directory structure changed.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what you are looking for. All the other answers don't understand that you were working from an OS book. Please refer to the link provided on the site.

http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/Code/code.intro.tgz

```c
#ifndef __common_h__
#define __common_h__

#include <sys/time.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <pthread.h>

double GetTime() {
    struct timeval t;
    int rc = gettimeofday(&t, NULL);
    assert(rc == 0);
    return (double)t.tv_sec + (double)t.tv_usec/1e6;
}

void Spin(int howlong) {
    double t = GetTime();
    while ((GetTime() - t) < (double)howlong)
    ; // do nothing in loop
}

void Pthread_create(pthread_t *t, const pthread_attr_t *attr,  
    void *(*start_routine)(void *), void *arg) {
    int rc = pthread_create(t, attr, start_routine, arg);
    assert(rc == 0);
}

void Pthread_join(pthread_t thread, void **value_ptr) {
    int rc = pthread_join(thread, value_ptr);
    assert(rc == 0);
}

void Pthread_mutex_lock(pthread_mutex_t *mutex) {
    int rc = pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
    assert(rc == 0);
}

void Pthread_mutex_unlock(pthread_mutex_t *mutex) {
    int rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);
    assert(rc == 0);
}

void Pthread_mutex_init(pthread_mutex_t *mutex, pthread_mutexattr_t *attr) {
    int rc = pthread_mutex_init(mutex, attr);
    assert(rc == 0);
}


#endif // __common_h__
```

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration of main function should follow that declared in `common.h`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "common.h"

// not this:
//int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
// but:
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *argv2[]) {
    return 0;
}
```

and compile your code with something like:

```
gcc cpu.c common.h -Wall -o cpu
```

Answer (score 0):

Spin(1) is the same as sleep(1), so I will just use sleep()

Answer (score -1):

common.h is not standard header to be added. If you want to compile and run this piece of code whether find common.h which contains Spin() or compile and run your code with out Spin() and common. Omitting Spin() and common.h will not have effect on the understanding of discussion provided in the book

Comment: Do you how to find the common.h?

Comment: See below - I found the `common.h` file you were missing.